# Вопрос про сессии php

Tags: php, сессия

Хотел спросить можно на сессиях делать такое, допустим мы задаем 60 секунд, если прошла эта 60 секунд показать другой код, и как реализовать?

Comment: ну через 60 секунд сессия у вас становится не активной, в чём проблема то?

Comment: как-бы непонятно причем здесь сессии... ну конечно можно в сессию положить текущее время и сравнивать это время при последующих обращениях.

@Алексей Скляр, что вы имели ввиду ? почему сессия становится неактивной через 60 секунд ?

Comment: @FunnY77, Перефразируйте, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос: исправьте грамматические ошибки, правильно расставьте запятые. Если ещё добавите побольше уточняющей информации, то Вы ускорите получение ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно

```
<?php

  session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['times']))
    {
    if($_SESSION['times']+60<time()){
    require_once("one_script.php");
    exit();}
    }
    require_once("two_script.php");
    ?>
```